# Update/insert meta_key and meta_value in wp_postmeta

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin, yoast

I have a website with coupons and a large database. In wp_postmeta most of my posts have a store_id, because I use the plugin Yoast SEO and it sets the meta_key and the meta_value. Not all of my coupons have a store_id in the wp_postmeta, like the older coupons or some of them who was copied from the old ones, or who came automatically through API.

If I update every coupon and re-click the store part, the post gets the store_id written in the table wp_postmeta. But I have more than 50 000 coupons... I need the store_id set for every coupon I have, for other tasks I need to do.

Is there an easier way how to do this, without manually updating every coupon?

Answer (score 0):

First, please make a backup.

If I understand correctly, yoiu need to change *every* row in the `wp_postmeta` table to set the `store_id` to the same value. If I've misunderstood in some way, that is, if you need to set a different value for some rows or if you don't want to over-write existing data, you should stop reading here. I don't know anything about Yoast SEO and only know as much as I've perceived from your post here.

But changing a single column for all rows is easy. You need an SQL statement something like this:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `store_id`=1
```

That will change the `store_id` of every row in `wp_postmeta` to 1.

Since you've tagged phpMyAdmin, presumably you're using that as your interface. Just click the SQL tab once you're in your WordPress database to enter the text of the query directly there.